# How to merge k number of sorted lists?

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, merge

```
def merge(list1, list2):
    results = []
    while list1 and list2:
        if list1[0] < list2[0]:
            results.append(list1.pop(0))
        else:
            results.append(list2.pop(0))
    results.extend(list1)
    results.extend(list2)
    return results
```

Here is the standard algorithm to merge 2 sorted lists into 1. However, how can we merge multiple sorted lists into 1?

```
l = [[8, 10, 12], [4, 5, 9], [2, 11]]  
merge(l)  
>>> [2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-way_merge_algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your own `merge` with [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce

l = [[8, 10, 12], [4, 5, 9], [2, 11]]

merged = reduce(merge, l)
print(merged)
# [2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

This has running time *O(kn)*. You could merge (unique) pairs until you have 1 final list left, which would improve it to *O(n log k)* (as the number of lists to merge reduces by half every time).

Comment: sorting is faster when k approaches sqrt(n)

Comment: @ChristianSloper *O(n log k)* will always we be at least as good as or better than *O(n log n)* (as *k <= n*). But yes, *O(kn)* with a simple `reduce` is not that great for large *k*. The problem with sorting all over again is that you're not taking advantage of the fact that the sub lists are already sorted.

Comment: Agreed, my comment was in response to the code, I didn't see your comment improving to n log k.

Answer (score 4):

You could implement [direct k-way merge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-way_merge_algorithm#Direct_k-way_merge) using a [heap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) and [queues](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

```
import heapq
from collections import deque


def k_merge(*lists):
    queues = [queue for queue in map(deque, lists)]

    heap = []
    for i, lst in enumerate(queues):
        heap.append((lst.popleft(), i))

    heapq.heapify(heap)

    result = []
    while heap:
        value, index = heapq.heappop(heap)
        result.append(value)

        if queues[index]:
            heapq.heappush(heap, (queues[index].popleft(), index))

    return result


print(k_merge(*[[8, 10, 12], [4, 5, 9], [2, 11]]))
```

**Output**

```
[2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

If you have `k` lists and `n` elements this approach is `O(nlogk)`

Comment: @OlivierMelançon Updated the answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can just sort it using `sorted()`:

```
from itertools import chain

l = [[8, 10, 12], [4, 5, 9], [2, 11]]

sorted(chain(*l))
```

Gives result:

```
[2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Comment: Although, this is O(nlog(n))

Answer (score 1):

An easy and efficient way is [heapq.merge](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge):

```
>>> lists = [[8, 10, 12], [4, 5, 9], [2, 11]]
>>> list(heapq.merge(*lists))
[2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Glancing at [CPython's implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/heapq.py#L314), it looks similar to the [direct k-way merge answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52821454/1031434), so I would *guess* that `heapq.merge` is `O(n log(k))` as well, though the docstring does not guarantee this.

Answer (score 0):

Flatten with list comprehension and then sort

```
print(sorted([j for i in l for j in i]))
# [2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from Queue import PriorityQueue

class Solution(object):
    def mergeKLists(self, lists):
        """
        :type lists: List[ListNode]
        :rtype: ListNode
        """
        head = point = ListNode(0)
        q = PriorityQueue()
        for l in lists:
            if l:
                q.put((l.val, l))
        while not q.empty():
            val, node = q.get()
            point.next = ListNode(val)
            point = point.next
            node = node.next
            if node:
                q.put((node.val, node))
        return head.next
```

Using a Priority Queue optimizes the comparison process

1. Time Complexity: O(n log(k)) where k is the number of linked lists:

   - The comparison cost will be reduced to O(log k) for every pop and insertion to priority queue. But finding the node with the smallest value just costs O(1) time.
2. Space Complexity:

   - O(n) Creating a new linked list costs O(n) space
   - O(k) The code above present applies in-place method which cost O(1) space.
   - And the priority queue(often implemented with heaps) costs O(k) space (it's far less than N in most situations)